# Looking for a one line JavaScript to do this logic

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a filter that checks to see if the record I have is set to saturday and it is saturday, then return true.  If the record I have is set to sunday, and it's sunday, then return true.

```
function(rec) {
  if (rec.sat === true && day === "sat") return true;
  if (rec.sun === true && day === "sun") return true;
})
```

Seems like I should be able to make this really simple but my brain is not figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this in a single `if`:

```
if (rec[day] === true) return true;
```

Assuming that the properties of `rec` and value of `day` have the same case: eg. `rec.mon` and `mon`, `rec.wed` and `wed`.

If all you are doing is returning true then you can do it even simpler:

```
return rec[day] === true;
```

You will sometimes see people write this as `return !!rec[day]` which does the same thing but is not as readable IMHO.

If you don't care about possibly returning `undefined` then you can even do:

```
return rec[day];
```

Comment: Or `return rec[day] === true`? (If that's the only logic in the fn, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function(rec) {
  return  (day==="sun" || day === "sat") && (rec[day] === true) 
}
```